# How I can reset variable value when function end?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, ecmascript-6

I have such function and global variable (as array):

```
const arraysList = []

export const changeColorCategories = (array, draggedColumnId) => {
    const isColor = arraysList.length ? arraysList[0][0]?.color : [];

    if (typeof isColor === 'string') {
        firstLevelColor = isColor;
    }

    return array.map((item, index, categories) => {
        item.color = draggedColumnId !== 3 ? '#010172' : '#000000';
        arraysList.push(categories);
        
        if (firstLevelColor && !draggedColumnId) {
            item.color = firstLevelColor;
        }

        if (item?.children?.length) {
            changeColorCategories(item.children);
        }
        
        return item;
    })
}
```

Every call of this function push some data to array. In this function I use recursion. So how i can clear this array only when this function will end it's work.

Comment: Can you add some example input, how the function is called, and what you're expected outputs are meant to look like?

Comment: You can just create a sub function that does the recursion, rather than doing recursion directly on the caller.

Comment: @Keith can you show me simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the recursion function inside another function this way you can run anything you want when the function ends

```
const arraysList = []

export const changeColorCategories = (array, draggedColumnId) => {
    const isColor = arraysList.length ? arraysList[0][0]?.color : [];

    if (typeof isColor === 'string') {
        firstLevelColor = isColor;
    }

    return array.map((item, index, categories) => {
        item.color = draggedColumnId !== 3 ? '#010172' : '#000000';
        arraysList.push(categories);
        
        if (firstLevelColor && !draggedColumnId) {
            item.color = firstLevelColor;
        }

        if (item?.children?.length) {
            changeColorCategories(item.children);
        }
        
        return item;
    })
} 

function runRucFunc(){
    const result = changeColorCategories();
    //Your other code goes here

    return result;
}
```

Comment: As you can see my main function return some data, but in this case it doesn't.

Comment: @Gover123 I've edited the answer, take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your recursion part inside a sub function.

Below I've called the inner function `inner`, I've also moved the arrayList into the function, due to closures you wound't even need to clear the arrayList, it would be cleared automatically as it goes out of scope.

eg.

```
export const changeColorCategories = (array, draggedColumnId) => {

    const arraysList = []

    function inner(array, draggedColumnId) {
        const isColor = arraysList.length ? arraysList[0][0]?.color : [];

        if (typeof isColor === 'string') {
            firstLevelColor = isColor;
        }

        return array.map((item, index, categories) => {
            item.color = draggedColumnId !== 3 ? '#010172' : '#000000';
            arraysList.push(categories);
        
            if (firstLevelColor && !draggedColumnId) {
               item.color = firstLevelColor;
            }

            if (item?.children?.length) {
                inner(item.children);  //we call inner here instead.
            }
        
            return item;
        })
   }
   // now call our inner 
   // you could do something even before your recursion.
   const result = inner(array, draggedColumnId);
   // here we can put what we want after recursion.
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the recursive call in another function like so:

```js
const arr = []

const recursive = (counter = 0) => {
    if(counter === 5)
      return arr.map((v) => String.fromCodePoint(65 + v))

    arr.push(counter)  
    return recursive(++counter)
}

const go = () => {
  console.log(recursive()) // [A,B,C,D,E]
  console.log(arr) // [0,1,2,3,4]
  arr.length = 0   // clear the array
  console.log(arr) // []
}

go()
```

Alternatively, if the global array does not actually need to be global, and is merely a container for working information of the recursive algorithm, then you could make it a parameter of the recursive function, which will then fall out of scope (and be garbage collected) when the recursion ends.

```js
const recursive = (counter = 0, arr = []) => {
    if(counter === 5)
      return arr.map((v) => String.fromCodePoint(65 + v))

    arr.push(counter)  
    return recursive(++counter, arr)
}

console.log(recursive()) // [A,B,C,D,E]
console.log(arr) // Error! Not in scope!

go()
```

Or, you could make the recursive function more intelligent and able to detect when it is processing the final recursion: how this is done will depend on the precise logic of the recursive function.